# OpenVPN Connects but can't see network

Tags: openvpn

I can connect to the firewall but cannot get to the lan.  The lan can ping the interface of the open vpn gateway.  My workstation cannot ping the interface of the openvpn gateway.  I tried setting a route on my workstation but no change.  I have tried both UDP and TCP connections and have added explicit rules to the LAN interface.

Answer (score 0):

The "server-side" of OpenVPN creates a virtual network interface on that end, usually `tun0`.  So, on the system that you are connecting to, that system will have an `eth0`, `lo`, and then a `tun0`.

However, if nothing on the "server-side" is telling that system to forward packets coming in from `tun0` to anywhere else, it won't.  Linux systems are usually not set to "promiscuously route" by default.

If you are the one operating OpenVPN on the "server-side," you need to look into setting up basic routing, first by `echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` (I think), and then setting it up some basic firewall/access control rules with `iptables` since, after all, you just turned that machine into a router.  This must be done if you want to reach hosts other than the one the `openvpn` instance is running on.  Alternatively you can cobble up some quick "static port address translation" with `rinetd`, `nc` or similar tools.

Again, all this must be done on the "server-side."  You can't do anything on your end, the "client" end.

Comment: There is the 'push' server configuration directive that will do that very easily, assuming that is what the problem is.  Also, how do you know he's using Linux?

Comment: This is the standalone version of pfsense.  Not sure if that is an option.  I can't find any info on doing that.

Comment: its running on FreeBSD

Comment: I went ahead and made this addition to the sysctl.conf  net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
and rebooted.  Behavior didn't change

Comment: The `push` server configuration will push routes to the client.  On the server side, you need to set up routing manually.  I've never set up routing on FreeBSD, but you might need to do more than the sysctl you did.

Comment: I have tried a push route on the server and I am getting this

Comment: I reentered the push command and that corrected it.  Thanks

Comment: (scratches head)